# Driver loaded for lircd is not the one I specify

Tags: raspberry-pi3, lirc

I am currently trying to write some code for using a remote control with a Raspberry Pi 3.

I installed LIRC according to a tutorial and it does work, but:

In the `/etc/lirc/hardware.conf` I have a line:

```
DRIVER="default"
```

but when I run `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` it says: `Using driver devinput on device /dev/lirc0`, which is giving wrong me the output.

I suspect this is also the reason why `irw` shows nothing when I run it and press buttons on my remote.

When I run `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0 -H default` it works just fine, but I can't specifiy that when running `irw`. (Or anything else that depends on LIRC)

Why is LIRC ignoring the `DRIVER`-line?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the lirc version; the debian packaging is part of the issue.

lirc as of 0.9.0, a really old version, has been part of debian for a (too) long time while the project has advanced. The hardware.conf file is part of the debian packaging of 0.9.0 (it has never been part of the upstream project).

Some years (2?) debian finally took the step to modernize lirc, and as part of this the hardware.conf file is not used, replaced by several files. lirc_options.conf is one of them. This makes lirc on debian work ín the same way as other distributions.

The official guide to lirc configuration is http://lirc.org/html/configuration-guide.html. Please disregard anything involving hardware.conf if your lirc is beyond 0.9.0 - it is by definition docs broken beyond repair.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my own answer, I found that LIRC igores the `hardware.conf` (however I didn't know why, thank you for clarifying the version dependency). It is really annoying that there are a lot of tutorials out there which teach the `hardware.conf`-way altough it's not working at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the standard driver was not `default` but `devinput`:

It seems the driver for LIRC to use isn't actually to be specified in `hardware.conf` but in `/etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf`.

If I now run `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` it uses `default` as driver.

However, this didn't, as I hoped, resolve my issues with `irw`.